# C using scanf() for | delimited string

Tags: c

I want to input a few strings then two integers. Whilst the strings are separated by '|', the integers are kept apart by a '.'.

Looking around online I have seen some sort of syntax which involves `[^]`. I am using this but it is not working at all.  Can someone please point out what I should be doing and why what I am doing is wrong?

```
sscanf(str, "%s[^|],%s[^|],%s[^|],%i[^|],%i[^.]", …);
```

Comment: Try `%[^|]|` for starters. The `s` is pointless.

Comment: Rather than just describing your input format, why not add an example?  Also "*looking around online*" - post a link!.  More complete code would be helpful too - that's an incomplete statement.

Comment: maybe `sscanf(str,"%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|]|%i.%i`

Answer (score 4):

The syntax is arcane at best — I'd suggest using a different approach such as `strtok()`, or parsing with string handling functions `strchr()` etc.

However the first thing you must realise is that the `%[^<delimiter-list>]` format specifier (a 'scan set' in the jargon, documented by POSIX [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html)
amongst many other places) only extracts string fields — you have to convert the extracted strings to integer if that is what they represent.

Secondly you still have to include the delimiter as a literal match character outside of the format specifier — you have separated the format specifiers with commas where `|` are in the input stream.

Consider the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a[32] ;
    char b[32] ;
    char c[32] ;
    char istr[32] ;  // Buffer for string representation of i
    int i ;
    int j ;          // j can be converted directly as it is at the end.

    // Example string
    char str[] = "fieldA|fieldB|fieldC|15.27" ;

    int converted = sscanf( str, "%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^.].%i", a, b, c, istr, &j ) ;

    // Check istr[] has a field before converting
    if( converted == 5 )
    {
        sscanf( istr, "%i", &i) ;
        printf( "%s, %s %s, %d, %d\n", a, b, c, i, j ) ;
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Fail -  %d fields converted\n", converted ) ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Best answer of the bunch.  Too bad OP gone over 40 days has yet accepted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work...

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{

char x[32] = "abc|def|123.456.";
char y[20];
char z[20];
int i =0;
int j =0;
sscanf(x,"%[^|]|%[^|]|%d.%d.",y,z,&i,&j);
fprintf(stdout,"1:%s 2:%s 3:%d 4:%d\n",y,z,i,j);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use either `[]` or `s` construct, but not both **and** your format string must incluse the separators.

So you should write something like :

```
sscanf(str, "%[^|]|%[^|]|...",...)
```