# Reading a file with a character as its separator in C

Tags: c, data-structures

I have this file, `database.txt`:

```
JOHN~DOE~21~MIYA MICHELLE~SMITH~22~
```

As you can see, I am using the character `~` to seperate the different information.

The problem is I cant read it. I want to use `~` rather than `SPACE` because some first names has two names like `MIYA MICHELLE`.

Here is the fuction I wrote:

```
void viewContacts(CONTACTS x)
{
    FILE *fp;

    if(openFile(&fp,'r')==1) // just a function I created for fopen();
    {

        while(fscanf(fp,"%s~%s~%s~",x.name.fn,x.name.ln,x.name.age)==3)
        {
            printf("%s %s %s",x.name.fn,x.name.ln,x.name.age);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

I tried using `SPACE` to separate the informations and tried to use the function above, it works successfully. But when I use `~`, it fails.

Comment: Is it by storing the `~` into a character the correct way or the only way?

Comment: You need to use a negated scan set: `%[^~]` to match anything that isn't a `~`.  `%s` matches anything that isn't white space (blank, tab, newline — roughly) which is why it worked when blanks were used in place of `~`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Like this? `while(fscanf(fp,"%[^~]s%[^~]s%[^~]s",x.name.fn,x.name.ln,x.name.age)==3)`

Comment: Almost; drop the s's.  The scan set is complete at the `]` and is not followed by the `s`.

Comment: It works when I add `~` after the `]` and delete the s. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842436/c-using-scanf-for-delimited-string

Comment: Yes — that's how it should work; sorry for the minor misdirection.  There are disadvantages to trying to deal with complex syntax issues while walking a dog late at night and using a cell phone to respond instead of a laptop computer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the help.